# Spring ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource VS ResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Hi I am trying to configure message sources in my Spring MVC web application .

I have currently got it running with ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource but I am not able to get it running with ResourceBundleMessageSource . I would have preferred to use ResourceBundleMessageSource because I dont need the Reload capability and ResourceBundleMessageSource is slightly more efficient.

in my rootApplicationContext , I have defined the beans as follows.

```
        <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/resources/locale/messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver" />

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**This works FINE ..**

But as soon as I change to

```
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/resources/locale/messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

The application breaks with the exception :

> 12:35:57,433 ERROR
> [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SpringJAXWS].[jsp]]
> (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp
> threw exception: org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException
> including path '/jsp/views/layout/top.jsp'.   at
> org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:241)
> [tiles-servlet-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]   at
> org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:105)
> [tiles-jsp-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]

HELP !

### The Entire project code is available at GITHUB

https://github.com/localghost8080/JaxWS

## Here is the entire stack trace for all who are interested.

https://github.com/localghost8080/JaxWS/blob/master/ResourceBundleException.txt

Comment: Did you check your Tiles configuration? it may be related to TilesViewResolver

Comment: Please post the full stack trace instead of a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

ResourceBundleMessageSource uses a different format for passing basename values

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="resources.locale.messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
```